# setMeta не прописывает часть тегов title и description в шаблон

Tags: php

начал изучать php и столкнулся с проблемой, при прописании функций setMeta и getMeta на странице в шаблоне не отображается часть тегов, а точнее title и description , хотя keywords срабатывает отлично.
Помогите разобраться!?

```
<?php

namespace ishop\base;

abstract class Controller{//прописываем базу контроллеров

    //Свойства контроллеров
    public $route;
    public $controller; 
    public $model;
    public $view;
    public $prefix;
    public $layout;
    public $data =[];
    public $meta = ['title' => '', 'description' => '', 'keywords' => ''];

    //конструктор где заполненяем данные
    public function __construct($route){
        $this->route = $route; 
        $this->controller = $route['controller'];
        $this->model = $route['controller'];
        $this->view = $route['action'];
        $this->prefix = $route['prefix'];
    }

    public function getView(){//получает объект вида и вызывает render
        $viewObject = new View($this->route, $this->layout, $this->view, $this->meta);//создаем объекты вида
        $viewObject->render($this->data);//создаем объект рендер с помощью data
    }

    //функция для передачи данных в $data
    public function set($data){
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    //функция для мета данных
    public function setMeta($title = '', $description = '', $keywords = ''){
        $this->meta['title'] = $title;
        $this->meta['description'] = $description;
        $this->meta['keywords'] = $keywords;
    }

}
```

```
<?php

namespace ishop\base;

class View{

    //Создаем базовый материал для вывода контроллеров при отладки
    public $route;
    public $controller; 
    public $model;
    public $view;
    public $prefix;
    public $layout;
    public $data =[];
    public $meta = [];

    public function __construct($route, $layout = '', $view = '', $meta){
        $this->route = $route; 
        $this->controller = $route['controller'];
        $this->view = $view;
        $this->model = $route['controller'];
        $this->prefix = $route['prefix'];
        $this->meta = $meta;
        if($layout === false){//Проверяем отключен ли Лайаут
            $this->layout = false;
        }else{
            $this->layout = $layout ?: LAYOUT;//если нет то подключаем массив шаблона или шаблон по умолч
        }
    }

    public function render($data){//формиркет страницу для пользователя
        $viewFile = APP . "/views/{$this->prefix}{$this->controller}/{$this->view}.php";//из 
        //формируем путь к Layout
        ob_start();//помещаем в буфер
        if(is_file($viewFile)){//если существует такой файл
            require_once $viewFile;//подключаем его
            $content = ob_get_clean();//из буфера в $content и чистим буфер
        }else{
            throw new \Exception("Не найден вид {$viewFile}", 500);//если нет ошибка 500
        }
        if(false !== $this->layout){//проверяем не отключен ли шаблон
            $layoutFile = APP . "/views/layouts/{$this->layout}.php";//если ок,формируем путь к шаблону
            if(is_file($layoutFile)){//выводим шаблон на экран
                require_once $layoutFile;
            }else{
                throw new \Exception("Не найден шаблон {$this->layout}", 500);
            }
        }
    }

    public function getMeta(){//метод пердачи инфы из метатэгов
        $output = '<title>' . $this->meta['title'] . '</title>' . PHP_EOL;
        $output = '<meta name="description" content="' . $this->meta['description'] . '">' . PHP_EOL;
        $output = '<meta name="keywords" content="' . $this->meta['keywords'] . '">' . PHP_EOL;
        return $output;
    }


}
```

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

class MainController extends AppController{

    public function indexAction(){
/*      echo __METHOD__ ;*/
    $this->setMeta('Главная', 'Описание', 'Клю');
    }
}
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <?=$this->getMeta();?>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>Шаблон DEFAULT</h1>

    <?=$content;?>

</body>
</html>
```

И на деле выходит так

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Клю">
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>Шаблон DEFAULT</h1>

    <h1> Hello, Urod </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$output = '<title>' . $this->meta['title'] . '</title>' . PHP_EOL;
$output = '<meta name="description" content="' . $this->meta['description'] . '">' . PHP_EOL;
$output = '<meta name="keywords" content="' . $this->meta['keywords'] . '">' . PHP_EOL;
```

Вы перезаписываете значение `$output` каждый раз. Следовательно в переменной `$output` будет только последнее присвоение. Используйте оператор `.=` для добавления:

```
$output = '<title>' . $this->meta['title'] . '</title>' . PHP_EOL;
$output .= '<meta name="description" content="' . $this->meta['description'] . '">' . PHP_EOL;
$output .= '<meta name="keywords" content="' . $this->meta['keywords'] . '">' . PHP_EOL;
```

Для работы с Meta я написал свой класс, можете посмотреть и воспользоваться, если будет актуально: https://github.com/mepihindeveloper/phpframework/blob/develop/kernel/helpers/MetaTag.php

Comment: Спасибо, я думал об этом, но не знал как реализовать!